# Change multiple files content type programatically using CSOM for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to change all the files in a library from one content type to another. This is in SharePoint Online so I'm using the CSOM. I am new to this so I'm stuck at where to go from what I have below.

I think my biggest issue is getting the values of the content types. That and I'm so used to SP On Premise I'm having trouble grasping this CSOM stuff. Much thanks to anyone that can help point me in the right direction!

```
#Load necessary module to connect to SPOService
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null

#Login Information for script
$User = "user"
$Pass = "password"
$WebUrl = "SiteURL"

#Connect to SharePoint Online service
Write-Host "Logging into SharePoint online service." -ForegroundColor Green
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl)
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force))

#Get the Necessary List
Write-Host "Getting the required list." -ForegroundColor Green
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLibrary")

Write-Host "Getting the Content Types." -ForegroundColor Green
$oldCT = $list.ContentTypes("OldCTName")
$newCT = $list.ContentTypes("NewCTName")
$newCTID = $newCT.ID

$Query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(1000); 
$Items = $List.GetItems($Query);

$Context.Load($Items);
$Context.ExecuteQuery();

#Check if the values specified for the content types actually exist on the list
    if (($oldCT -ne $null) -and ($newCT -ne $null))
    {
        #Go through each item in the list
        #Edit existing list items
    foreach($item in $Items)
    {
            #Check if the item content type currently equals the old content type specified
            if ($_.ContentType.Name -eq $oldCT.Name)
            {
                #Check the check out status of the file
                if ($_.File.CheckOutType -eq "None")
                {
                    #Change the content type association for the item
                    $_.File.CheckOut()
                    write-host "Resetting content type for file" $_.Name "from" $oldCT.Name "to" $newCT.Name
                    $_["ContentTypeId"] = $newCTID
                    $_.Update()
                    $_.File.CheckIn("Content type changed to " + $newCT.Name, 1)
                }
                else
                {
                    write-host "File" $_.Name "is checked out to" $_.File.CheckedOutByUser.ToString() "and cannot be modified"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                write-host "File" $_.Name "is associated with the content type" $_.ContentType.Name "and shall not be modified"
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "One of the content types specified has not been attached to the list"$list.Title
    }
        $Context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: At a glance your script looks ok. What is it that's not working?